# Download multiple files in an external hard drive

Tags: command-line, hard-drive, external-hdd, wget

I am trying to download multiple files in an external hard drive.

I did lots of try but did not succeed:

1. write the links in a separate file `data.txt`
2. `wget -i data.txt /directory of external drive`
3. `wget --directory-prefix="directory of path where i want to download" data.txt`

I am not successful yet... Can somebody guide me how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path.

Why not just combine the last two steps for the desired effect:

```
cd /somepath ; wget -i /anotherpath/data.txt
```

Or:

```
wget -i /anotherpath/data.txt --directory-prefix=/somepath
```

Comment: @KanwalShahzadi If this answer solve your question , please do not forget to accept it.